# Rewrite cond - What is actually doing?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a WP instance, and I see that any time I write a URL that has any string that contains 'moz' it errors out with a 404.

I have taken a look at my .htaccess looking for 'moz' and I see this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moz(.*)
```

Why would that be causing a 404?

EDIT: The context of this RewriteCond

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/knowledge/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/midphase(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moz(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Stats/(.*)
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: and that is the entire htaccess rules set?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone added WordPress to a website with existing content. Those rewrite conditions check to see if the URL is for one of the existing folders, and if not, send the request to index.php.

That means of you enter a URL that starts with moz and points to a file that doesn't exist, you'll get a 404.

Comment: So, how do I avoid that to happen? I want to be able to write my URLS with the moz word in it.

Comment: If you don't want the rewrite to happen, you could delete that rewrite condition. Make sure you don't still need it for something, though.

Comment: Can't I just delete the condition? RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moz(.*)

Comment: That will fix it, yeah.

Comment: I am wondering what is happening though, why do I get the 404 just if the name contains moz? I mean, you are saying that the conditions check if the URL is for one of the existing folders? What does that mean? I know that I create a file in my WP and I just say that the URL is called 'moz-test' - SO that file is there. What is going on?

Comment: All I can guess is that you're entering the URL wrong, then. There's a rewrite condition that makes sure the file doesn't exist before rewriting.